# Making String data structure more efficient in java

Tags: java, oop, data-structures

I have the task and homework of creating a data structure that would make the programs given work, it basically generates random nonsensical words and you need to create a data structure that stores them, can add, count and remove them. This is what I have so far but need to make it more efficient, a lot more efficient. Also I can't use the Java API.

```
public class WordStoringTest implements WordStore {
private StringBuilder[] words;
private int[] array;
private int[] abcdefg;
private int[] hijklmn;
private int[] opqrstu;
private int[] vwxyz;

private int n;

public WordStoringTest(int n) {
    this.n = n;
    this.words = new StringBuilder[n];
    this.array = new int[n];    
    this.abcdefg = new int[n];
    this.hijklmn = new int[n];
    this.opqrstu = new int[n];
    this.vwxyz = new int[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        abcdefg[i] = 0;
        hijklmn[i] = 0;
        opqrstu[i] = 0;
        vwxyz[i] = 0;
    }
}

public void add(String word) {
    StringBuilder word2 = new StringBuilder(word);
    int i = word2.hashCode(); 
    StringBuilder[] newWords = new StringBuilder[this.words.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(this.words, 0, newWords, 0, this.words.length);
    newWords[newWords.length - 1] = word2;
    this.words = newWords;  
    if(word.charAt(0) >= 'a' && word.charAt(0) <= 'g'){
        int count =0;
        for(int a=0; a<abcdefg.length; a++){
            if(abcdefg[count] !=0){
                count++;
            }
        }
        int[] arrayTemp = new int[count+1];
        int c =0;
        for(int v = 0; v<abcdefg.length; v++){
            if(abcdefg[v] !=0){
                arrayTemp[v] = abcdefg[v];
                c++;
            }
        }
        arrayTemp[c] = i;
        abcdefg = arrayTemp;
    }
    else if(word.charAt(0) >= 'h' && word.charAt(0) <= 'n'){
        int count =0;
        for(int a=0; a<hijklmn.length; a++){
            if(hijklmn[count] !=0){
                count++;
            }
        }

        int[] arrayTemp = new int[count+1];
        int c =0;
        for(int v = 0; v<hijklmn.length; v++){
            if(hijklmn[v] !=0){
                arrayTemp[v] = hijklmn[v];
                c++;
            }
        }
        arrayTemp[c] = i;
        hijklmn = arrayTemp;
    }
    else if(word.charAt(0) >= 'o' && word.charAt(0) <= 'u'){
        int count =0;
        for(int a=0; a<opqrstu.length; a++){
            if(opqrstu[count] !=0){
                count++;
            }
        }

        int[] arrayTemp = new int[count+1];
        int c =0;
        for(int v = 0; v<opqrstu.length; v++){
            if(opqrstu[v] !=0){
                arrayTemp[v] = opqrstu[v];
                c++;
            }
        }
        arrayTemp[c] = i;
        opqrstu = arrayTemp;
    }
    else if(word.charAt(0) >= 'v' && word.charAt(0) <= 'z'){
        int count =0;
        for(int a=0; a<vwxyz.length; a++){
            if(vwxyz[count] !=0){
                count++;
            }
        }
        int[] arrayTemp = new int[count+1];
        int c =0;
        for(int v = 0; v<vwxyz.length; v++){
            if(vwxyz[v] !=0){
                arrayTemp[v] = vwxyz[v];
                c++;
            }
        }
        arrayTemp[c] = i;
        vwxyz = arrayTemp;
    }
}

public int count(String word) {
    int i = word.hashCode();
    int count = 0;
    int[] temp = null;
    if(word.charAt(0) >= 'a' && word.charAt(0) <= 'g'){
        temp = abcdefg;
    }
    else if(word.charAt(0) >= 'h' && word.charAt(0) <= 'n'){
        temp = hijklmn;
    }
    else if(word.charAt(0) >= 'o' && word.charAt(0) <= 'u'){
        temp = opqrstu;
    }
    else if(word.charAt(0) >= 'v' && word.charAt(0) <= 'z'){
        temp = vwxyz;
    }

    for (int w = 0; w<temp.length; w++){
        if (array[w] == i) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public void remove(String word) {
    int pos = 0;
    StringBuilder[] temp = this.words;
    while (pos < temp.length) {
        StringBuilder w = temp[pos];
        if (w.equals(word)) {
            StringBuilder[] newTemp = new StringBuilder[temp.length - 1];
            if (pos == 0) {
                System.arraycopy(temp, 1, newTemp, 0, newTemp.length);
            } else if (pos == temp.length - 1) {
                System.arraycopy(temp, 0, newTemp, 0, newTemp.length);
            } else {
                System.arraycopy(temp, 0, newTemp, 0, pos);
                System.arraycopy(temp, pos + 1, newTemp, pos, newTemp.length - pos);
            }
            temp = newTemp;
        } else {
            pos++;
        }
    }
    this.words = temp;
    System.out.println("1" + "*");






    int posi = 0;
    int f = word.hashCode();
    int[] temps = this.array;
    while (posi < temps.length) {
        int g = temps[posi];
        if (g ==f) {
            int[] newTemps = new int[temps.length - 1];
            if (posi == 0) {
                System.arraycopy(temps, 1, newTemps, 0, newTemps.length);
            } else if (posi == temps.length - 1) {
                System.arraycopy(temps, 0, newTemps, 0, newTemps.length);
            } else {
                System.arraycopy(temps, 0, newTemps, 0, posi);
                System.arraycopy(temps, posi + 1, newTemps, posi, newTemps.length - posi);
            }
            temps = newTemps;
        } else {
            posi++;
        }
    }
    this.array = temps;

}
}
```

I know the remove method doesn't work :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do i make it more efficient?

Comment: ok ill change that now

Comment: Use a HashMap<String, Counter>. Problem solved.

Comment: Whenever possible use `int` instead `Integer` to reduce overhead of boxing un-boxing.

Comment: cant use java API sorry ill edit that in

Comment: StringBuilder, Integer and String are part of the Java API.

Comment: What the hell is this code doing? I've tried several times, but I can't figure it out!

Comment: the code given will add words by the amount said

Comment: it will generate words and add them , to make it more efficient i have split the words up into arrays by letter and them use their hashcodes

Comment: @user3080111 Do you know that makes the code faster, because it makes it much harder to understand?

Comment: You might not be able to use the builtin collections but you can write code which does the same thing.  No point in re-inventing how to store a collection unless you are really sure it will be better in some way.  BTW The Java collections were translated from collections written long before Java existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start,

- don't use StringBuffer, they were replaced by StringBuilder almost ten years ago and is slightly faster.
- don't use wrappers when you can use primitives.  This not only performs better but is much clearer as to intent. i.e. don't use an `Integer` if it can't be `null` and you don't need to.
- I would use an ArrayList as a list of StringBuilders, or I would grow the array the same way. i.e. double the size as required rather than increasing the size on every add()
- use range checks like `word.charAt(0) >= 'a' && word.charAt(0) <= 'g'`
- use counter more than once, you appear to move which counter to increment on every iteration which is baffling.
- as the code in each of the character ranges is basically the same you should be able to make the code the same and use a collection of counters instead of repeating the code.

From your description, it suggests the code should be far, far simpler. Like this

```
// unfortunately builtin collections force you to use wrappers. 
// Trove for example, does not.
final Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<>();
public void add(String word) {
    Integer count = wordCount.get(word);
    if (count == null)
        count = 0;
    wordCount.put(word, count+1);
}
public int count(String word) {
    Integer count = wordCount.get(word);
    return count == null ? 0 : count.intValue();
}
public void remove(String word) {
    Integer count = wordCount.get(word);
    if (count == null)
        return;
    if (count <= 1);
        wordCount.remove(word);
    else
        wordCount.put(word, count+1);
}
```

---

Using [Trove4j](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) by comparison

```
// No Integer wrappers needed.
final TObjectIntHashMap<String> wordCount = new TObjectIntHashMap<String>();
public void add(String word) {
    wordCount.adjustOrPutValue(word, 1, 1);
}
public int count(String word) {
    return wordCount.get(word);
}
public void remove(String word) {
    int count = wordCount.adjustOrPutValue(word, 0, -1);
    if (count <= 0);
        wordCount.remove(word);
}
```

Comment: thanks this is greatly helping, even the first three have increased the speed tremendously

Comment: thanks peter but not using the java api also means everyother api

Comment: @user3080111 You might not be able to use the builtin collections but you can write code which does the same thing. No point in re-inventing how to store a collection unless you are really sure it will be better in some way. BTW The Java collections were translated from collections written long before Java existed.   As has been pointed out, `String` is part of the Java API.

Comment: i have implemented some of the changes and updated the code and am getting speeds such as adding 100000 words takes 147741ms and that is still too much i think it should be more like 45ms not 147741ms, what more can i do?

Comment: @user3080111 As I suggested I would use a hash Map instead of arrays as you have.  If you can't use the built in APIs you can write it yourself.  I doesn't become a bad idea just because its in an API you can't use.  If you want to know how long it should take, use the APIs you are not allowed to use to at least time how long it should take.  Then you know what your target should be instead of guessing.

Comment: how do i start writing a hashmap, im not sure about how to start this or implment it, i know how a hashmap works, i think

Comment: I would start by reading the code in HashMap from its source.  Then you can write something which does the same thing.  You could even write it to be more efficient by using `int` instead of `Integer`

Comment: would i be able to implement that into my current code or would i have to start again?

Comment: Developers spend 90% of them time understanding the problem and only 10% of their time writing.  I would be included to rewrite the whole thing even if you want to keep half of it.

Comment: ok, apart from hashmaps, would breaking the abcdefg, into smaller arrays increase the speed or not at all?

Comment: @user3080111 it helps because adding one element at a time to an array, and growing it each time, is very expensive in fact it gets more expensive the longer the array.  If you use a hash map, it won't help at all, you wont need it and it will be much, much faster.